# Composer autoload.php AWS 500 error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

Hey everyone I am trying to deploy my website to AWS and I am getting an error (500 (Internal Server Error)) when it reaches the require line in my php, which is supposed to include Composer's vendor file, autoload.php. Weird thing is, it works fine on my local instance (and my group member's local instances) . Any ideas? Could aws be setting some sort of permissions? I tried including other php files that are outside of the vendor folder and they seem to work fine.

I test this by echoing before and after each line to figure out how far it compiles. It gets to "above require"

Thanks!
**UPDATE:** After the suggestion below, I am getting an error to read now, it is just below.

> Warning:
>   require(/var/app/current/vendor/composer/../facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/polyfills.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/app/current/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66 Fatal
>   error: require(): Failed opening required
>
> /var/app/current/vendor/composer/../facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/polyfills.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear7:/usr/share/php7') in
>   /var/app/current/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66

```
<?php
    echo "above session";
    session_start();
    echo "above require ";
    include '../vendor/autoload.php';
    //Testing this passed ->> include 'db.inc.php';
    //require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    echo "under require\n";
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => '',
        'app_secret' => '',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);
    echo "under facebook class dec\n";
```

Comment: try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` on top

Comment: Done. I updated the error, thanks

Comment: Do you have Facebook in `composer.js`? Do you see `Facebook` class in autoloader class map? Do you have actual file in autoloader specified location?

Comment: Yeap, it is in the composer.js file. The Facebook class also seems to be there as well. I followed down the path and the file is there as well. Very weird. Think I am going to manually install without composer and try that. Will post update, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to figure out what exactly was causing this issue, but to get the SDK to work I just did what Facebook recommended developers not to do, which is install it manually.

For anyone with this problem in the future, make sure to update all your requires or includes(threw some more errors ). Also remove your old composer dependency using built in composer functions!